# return index of max ascending array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

Here, I currently return the length of the max ascending array. However, I want to modify it such that I can return the index of the max ascending array. I tried setting idx = I inside the  `if (A[i] > A[i-1]) :`but that does not seem to work. What else could I try?

```
def func(A):

    n = len(A)
    m = 1
    l = 1
    idx = -1
      
    # traverse the array from the 2nd element
    for i in range(1, n) :
 
        # if current element if greater than previous
        # element, then this element helps in building
        # up the previous increasing subarray encountered
        # so far
        if (A[i] > A[i-1]) :
            l =l + 1
            idx = i-1
        else :
 
            # check if 'max' length is less than the length
            # of the current increasing subarray. If true,
            # then update 'max'
            if (m < l)  :
                m = l

            # reset 'len' to 1 as from this element
            # again the length of the new increasing
            # subarray is being calculated   
            l = 1
         
         
    # comparing the length of the last
    # increasing subarray with 'max'
    if (m < l) :
        m = l
      
    # required maximum length
    return m
```

Comment: If `A[i]` is less than `A[i-1]`, then `i-1` was the last index in a run of length `l`. The start index is therefore `i-l`.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the Problem requirements?  Or give some input and expected output?  What if the input array is - A = [5, 8, 6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, -1, 10]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
def func(A):
    n = len(A)
    m = 1
    l = 1
    index = [0,0]
    flag=0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if (A[i] > A[i-1]) :
            l =l + 1
            if flag==0:
                flag=1
                lindex = i-1
        else:
            if (m < l)  :
                m = l
                index = [lindex,i-1]
            flag=0
            l = 1
    if (m < l) :
        m = l
        index = [lindex,i]
        
    return index
```